# After updating to Paw 3, paw files will not open

Tags: updates, paw-app

As in the title, after updating the Paw (presumably version 2) client to Paw 3 - none of my `.paw` files will open.

Using the menu, all of my old files are now greyed out. Whenever I 'force' Paw to open my file in some way, the error I receive is as follows:

```
The document "__.paw" could not be opened. The file isn't in the correct format.

The file might be corrupted, truncated, or in an unexpected format.
```

This appears to be the case with every single `.paw` file I've created.

How can I migrate my original paw files to the new client? I see no feature to do so and am now severely regretting my decision to try the new features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry you had this issue.

This has been fixed in the latest release 3.0.4 it was an issue with 10.10. Can you drop us an email to support@paw.cloud if this persists.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure you do not have the old Paw app in your dock.  I went through upgrade as well and didn't realize I still had the old PAWs in my application folder.